# Adding Repositories Through Git Tower CLI for Dotfiles

Tags: git, git-tower

I'm working on my dotfiles and have a script that clones a quite a few of my repositories from GitHub and wanted to run `gittower pathtomyproject` in my shell script so that it will automatically add those repositories inside Tower. The problem is at this point I don't have the Git Tower CLI enabled.

Does anyone know how to enable the CLI from inside of a shell script so that I do have access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling the CLI in Tower is simply copying it into `/usr/local/bin`. The CLI tool itself resides in our App bundle at `Tower.app/Contents/MacOS/gittower`. You can copy it yourself or just use the script directly from there.